# Reducing mesh details while exporting to vector format SVG

Tags: graphics

I am trying to export a simple cuboid into .SVG format. In the output file, the cuboid is finely meshed, which increases the file size. How to remove this detailed mesh?

```
 Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "trial.svg"}], Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the svg file size reduced, I found this reduces it from 48k to 15k on windows 7, using V 9.01 `Export["trial.svg", Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], Cuboid[]}]]` This removes all face information.

Comment: @Nasser, your answer is already good enough for me, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This mesh depends on the whole size of the `Graphics3D`:

```
Export["trial.svg", Graphics3D[Cuboid[], PlotRange -> 5, Boxed -> False], 
   Background -> None]
```

It produces 2.8 KB file (15x reduction) on Linux without the detailed mesh

[image]

For further size reduction you can use compressed [SVGz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Compression) format

```
Export["trial.svgz", ...]
```

It produces 666 B file. This ability seems to be undocumented.

Comment: Nice! I wonder why ...

Comment: @ybeltukov, Your answer shows another example of undocumented attribute... Because in the documentation of SVG format there is no information about the `Background`. But I understand that the bounding box can itself takes some amount of file storage, so turning it off reduce file size. Thanks!

Comment: @saturasl The `Background` option is hidden in Details section in the documentation of [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html). See also my update about svgz format. A lot of applications can use it. It can be useful for you.